# Using Fancybox with Google Static Maps

Tags: javascript, fancybox, google-maps-static-api

**Setup**

- I have multiple links on a page with the class `location_link`
- Each Links `rel` attribute is equal to a city state combo (i.e.,`Omaha, NE`)
- Once the page is loaded, a JavaScript function loops through all of the `location_link`     items and binds a `click` event to them using jQuery.
- This click event fires a call to the Fancybox constructor that is supposed to show a Google Map of the location that link is associated with

**The Problem:**

Whenever I click on one of the "location links", I get the following error message:

> *The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.*

**Code I've Already Written:**

```
function setUpLocationLinks() {
    locationLinks = $("a.location_link");
    locationLinks.click(
        function() {
            var me = $(this);
            console.log(me.attr("href"));
            $.fancybox(
                {
                    "showCloseButton" : true,
                    "hideOnContentClick" : true,
                    "titlePosition"  : "inside",
                    "title" : me.attr("rel"),
                    "type" : "image"
                }
            )
            return false;
        }
    );
}
```

**Research I've Already Done:**

- The Google Static Map API no longer requires an API Key. The following is from the [Google Static Maps API Page](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)

> Note: The Google Static Maps API no longer requires a Maps API key!
>   (Google Maps API Premier customers should instead sign their URLs using a new cryptographic key which will be sent to you. See the Premier documentation for more information.)

- The [The Image URL](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=41.184344,%20-96.039441&size=500x500&format=jpg&maptype=road&sensor=false&markers=41.184344,%20-96.039441&zoom=10) I'm using does resolve and pulls back the data I need
- When I put the above mentioned URL into a standard <img> tag, the map shows up just fine.
- I'd like to pull this off without having to create some sort of dummy <img> tag that I'm constantly switching the `src` attribute out of.

Hopefully, you'll find this information helpful. Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. It uses an empty <img> tag, but it works. I'd love to see someone come up with a more graceful solution.

```
function setUpLocationLinks() {
    var locationLinks = $("a.location_link");
    var mapImage = $("#map_image");
    var mapImageContainer = $("#map_image_container");
    var mapFancybox = function() {
        $.fancybox.hideActivity();
        $.fancybox(
            {
                "showCloseButton" : true,
                "hideOnContentClick" : true,
                "titlePosition"  : "inside",
                "content" : mapImageContainer.html()
            }
        );
    }
    locationLinks.click(
        function() {
            var clickedLink = $(this);
            $.fancybox.showActivity();
            mapImage.attr("src", clickedLink.attr("href")).load(
                function() {
                    mapFancybox();
                }
            );
            if(mapImage.complete) {
                mapImage.triggerHandler("load");
            }
            return false;
        }
    );
}
```